# use variable of 'this' in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi I want to use 'this' variable in setInterval in a jquery function 
I write '// this code don't work' after don't worked line

```
 (function($)
            {
                $.fn.rotate=function () {
                    var counter=0;
                    var timer=setInterval(function () {
                        counter++;
                        var transform='rotate('+counter+'deg)';
                        $(this).css('transform',transform); // this code dont work
                        if(counter>=300)
                            clearInterval(timer);
                    },1);
                    return this;
                };
                $('#socialNetworks i').rotate();
            }(jQuery))
```

thanks Alot

Comment: yes but I don't understand that topic please send the answer with my code, my native language is not English and I don't understand that topic

Comment: The TL;DR is that the “callback” function passed to `setInterval` is called with `this` in the context of `setInterval`. You should either use an arrow function (`=>`) if possible, or use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to change the function’s `this` to the `this` in which it’s syntactically defined. Try to find documentation on how JavaScript’s `this` works in your native language.

Answer (score -2):

Using the arrow function when defining the function maintains the `this` context in which the function has been called. Thus you would be able to access `this` inside the function correctly.

```
( $ => {
    $.fn.rotate=function () {
        var counter=0;
        var timer=setInterval(function () {
            counter++;
            var transform='rotate('+counter+'deg)';
            $(this).css('transform',transform); // this code dont work
            if(counter>=300)
                clearInterval(timer);
        },1);
        return this;
    };
    $('#socialNetworks i').rotate();
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Where is the explanation that suggests how answer solves problem. It definitely doesn't. Code only answers with no explanation are somewhat useless. See [answer]